# Get a DataFrame with calculated value from 2 lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following 2 lists:

```
A=list(range(2018, 2023))

B=list(range(1,13))

Corresponding to A -> (2018,2019,2020,2021,2022) and 
                 B -> (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12).
```

I need to get the following DataFrame:

| ColumnA |
| --- |
| 201801 |
| 201802 |
| 201803 |
| 201804 |
| 201805 |
| 201806 |
| 201807 |
| 201808 |
| 201809 |
| 201810 |
| 201811 |
| 201812 |
| 201901 |
| 201902 |

And so on.

I can calculate those values like (A*100)+B, but I dont know how to obtain all values at once.

Comment: Are the lists important or are you just trying to generate these values? What do you mean obtain all values at once? Also `(A*100)+B` would not produce the shown output.

Comment: As an aside, if these are dates it would probably make more sense to generate them as dates _e.g._ `pd.date_range(start='2018', end='2023', freq='MS', inclusive='left').strftime('%Y%m')` (which, of course, only works if the lists aren't actually important to the data creation)

Comment: My mistake. The lists are already defined and fixed. I am trying to generate the DataFrame that I shown.(A*100)+B does not produce the output shown, but that is the way I am using to try to calculate those values. For example A[0]*100+B[0] gives me 201801.

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense. Are you looking for numeric output then in the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cross join ?:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['Year'])
df2= pd.DataFrame(B, columns=['Month'])

res = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')

# and if you want to concat them :
res['Column1'] = res['Year'].astype(str)+ res['Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

output:

```
> 
    Year  Month Column1
0   2018      1  201801
1   2018      2  201802
2   2018      3  201803
3   2018      4  201804
4   2018      5  201805
5   2018      6  201806
6   2018      7  201807
7   2018      8  201808
8   2018      9  201809
9   2018     10  201810
10  2018     11  201811
...
```

Comment: `res['Column1'] = (res['Year'] * 100 + res['Month']).astype(str)` is probably faster than string operations.